# Replicate View different servers

Tags: mysql, replication, view

Using MySQL, and related to this answer open in another thread ([How to replicate MySQL table in different servers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134743/how-to-replicate-mysql-table-in-different-servers)), It arises me the idea of replicating only a View in different servers (through master-slave)

To create a replicate-view without replicating original tables in remote server, is it possible? Or Do I have to replicate the tables as obligatory condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `VIEW` is a shorthand for accessing the underlying table(s).  If the table(s) are not there, the `VIEW` won't work.

You can reach into *other* servers via `FEDERATED`.  See also `Spider` (a 3rd party product).  Each has limitations.

Master-Slave is predicated that the Slave always contains an exact copy of the Master.  (There are exceptions, but your question does not hit any of them.)